# Is there a way to use MongoDB capped collections with Django's builtin logging module?

Tags: django, mongodb, logging, capped-collections

I'm interested in using MongoDB [capped collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) to log system activity on my Django project, in a similar way to what Django's [builtin logging module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) already does.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is a good approach. You can use the new psutil module to gather statistics, using it as cron job or a daemon, inserting the data into mongodb. Then use highcharts or something similar to display the data.

Inserting to a capped collection in mongodb from psutil is just about as easy as save(), once you set up the db document structure to hold the data you're interested in.

Here's a thread I just saw that shows how you could display it (you could use an ajax call to get the data from mongo instead of hardcoding like the example.

```
http://lime-technology.com/forum/index.php?topic=29186.0;nowap
```